# Intel C++ compiler integration in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, compiler-construction, intel

I want to do parallel programming using thread building blocks (tbb). The Intel C++ compiler provides tbb. Can someone help me integrate this compiler into Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: This is not a good place for "hold my hand" requests.  If you have specific problems with code, or a development tool, we can help you get unstuck.  But there's no answerable question here.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try reading the manual? Where are you stuck, exactly?  The Intel documentation for the compiler has a section entitled, "Using Microsoft Visual Studio" you could refer to and everything. http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/458838